# Pyautogui doesn't interact with other softwares

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a pyautogui program that clicks a specfic button when it appears in another software I have, the problem is that whenever I have the program running it doesn't move the mouse toards it with pyautogui.MoveTo() since the python program window is not active it should be active in order to move the mouse, this creates another issue, which is that whenever I will click the other program button it will be inactive again and the current active window will be the one of the software.

Note : by active I mean focused

```
import pyautogui
import time
pyautogui.FAILSAFE=False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        pyautogui.moveTo(10, 10)
        found = False
        try:
            button_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('confirm_button.png', confidence=0.8)
            if button_location is not None:
                button_center = pyautogui.center(button_location)
                x, y = int(button_center.x), int(button_center.y)
                pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
                pyautogui.click()
                found = True
        except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
            pass

        if found:
            print("Clicked 'Continue' button.")
            found = False

        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Could you clarify your issue?  Is the problem that `pyautogui.locateOnScreen()` is never successful (raising the `ImageNotFoundException`)?  Or is it only successful when either (a) the target program has focus or (b) the running Python script window has focus?  Or is it always locating the target correctly, but not moving to that location unless either the target program or Python window has focus?

Comment: It is only successful if the program has focus on the python exe or ide that's running it

Comment: I didn't have the problem have needing focus to be on the python.exe or ide (I'm using VSCode on Windows, running in the terminal).  However, I did find that despite what the documentation says, `pyautogui.,locateOnScreen()` is sometimes returning `None` and is not throwing the exception.  I tested this by adding print statements for both a return value of None and the exception, using the `6` button in Calculator as my target.  If I updated the script to not move the mouse pointer automatically after clicking, it couldn't find the button again as the mouse pointer changes the image match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem after some hours. Apparently, the software I was trying to automate had Admin privileges, in order to make the program able to access it using pyautogui, you will need to run the Python program as administrator as well.